# How to have one page show posts reverse-chronologically, but the others chronologically?

Tags: posts

I have a project-log type website where I store all of my progress on my projects. I want my home page to display all of my posts reverse-chronologically (so the visitors can see the newest pages first), but when you click on a category on the side and go to the category page, all of the posts are chronological, like a book.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You want a filter on `pre_get_posts` restricted to the home page. Something like:

```
function pregp_wpse_214875($qry) {
  if (is_home() && $qry->is_main_query()) {
    $qry->set('order','ASC');
  }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','pregp_wpse_214875');
```

You may need something other than `is_home()`, depending on how your "home page" is set up. The other most likely option would be `is_front_page()`

Comment: ps: we should avoid the `is_main_query()` within `pre_get_posts`, see the [source here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4/src/wp-includes/query.php#L750).  I think it can still be problematic in some cases to use `is_page()`/`is_front_page()` checks within the `pre_get_posts` hook. But I haven't checked the current status of the corresponding trac tickets.